# Speech recognition supported languages on Android

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I'm having a problem getting the supported languages. I have seen a solution 
that is to create a Broadcast receiver and fill the list with the languages.

```
public class LanguageChecker extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private List<String> supportedLanguages;

    private String languagePreference;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        //Log.d(Constants.Tag,"OnReceive");
        Bundle results = getResultExtras(true);
        if (results.containsKey(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE))
        {
            languagePreference =
                    results.getString(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE);
        }
        if (results.containsKey(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES))
        {
            supportedLanguages =
                    results.getStringArrayList(
                            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES);


        }
    }

    public List<String> getSupportedLanguages() {
        return supportedLanguages;
    }
}
```

but the problem is that I need this supportedLanguages list to fill my spinner.
When I call the method getSupportedLanguages, I get null.

This is how I use the broadcast within onCreate:

```
try {
    lang = new LanguageChecker();
    Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_GET_LANGUAGE_DETAILS);
    sendOrderedBroadcast(detailsIntent, null, lang, null, Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);


    supportedLanguagesForSpeech=lang.getSupportedLanguages();
    Log.d(Constants.Tag, String.valueOf(supportedLanguagesForSpeech.size()));
}
catch (Exception e){
    Log.d(Constants.Tag,e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should solve it with a callback to make sure that `supportedLanguages` is assigned. You are getting `null` because you are not waiting `onReceive` to be called.

Here is my current solution to querying all the available speech recognition services for their supported languages:

https://github.com/Kaljurand/K6nele/blob/3e514edc87e07babb0be57fa31ab48be7e2226e7/app/src/ee/ioc/phon/android/speak/RecognitionServiceManager.java

You can see it in action in the Kõnele app (http://kaljurand.github.io/K6nele/about/), in the "Settings -> Recognition languages & services" list.